# Navigation bar buttons won't stay in parent

Tags: html, css, navigation

I'm trying to make a navigation bar for my website, but the 'info' button will not stay inside the parent. Here is my HTML:

```
<div id="header">
<div id="homeB">
    <a href="" id="homeBTEXT">HOME</a>
</div>
<div id="infoB">
    <a href="" id="infoBTEXT">INFO</a>
</div>
</div>
<div id="main"></div>
```

And my CSS:

```
#header {
height:11%;
width:70%;
background:violet;
margin-left:15%;
}

#main {
height:100%;
width:70%;
background:blue;
margin-top:1%;
margin-left:15%;
}

ul {
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
display:inline-block;
}

#homeB {
width:20%;
height:100%;
background:red;
}

#homeBTEXT {
display:block; 
font-size:250%; 
text-align:center; 
text-decoration:none;
font-family:Impact, charcoal, sans-serif;
color:blue;
}

#infoB {
width:20%;
height:50px;
background:red;
float:right;
left:64.2%;
}

#infoBTEXT {
display:block; 
font-size:250%; 
text-align:center; 
text-decoration:none;
font-family:Impact, charcoal, sans-serif;
color:blue;
}
```

Could someone clear up why this is not working?
Thanks, I'm not great at a lot of HTML and CSS elements, so any extra help would be appreciated too :)

Answer (score 2):

Give `float: left;` to the `#homeBTEXT` and also clear the `#header`!

```
#homeBTEXT {
    display:block; 
    font-size:250%; 
    text-align:center; 
    text-decoration:none;
    font-family:Impact, charcoal, sans-serif;
    color:blue;
    float:left;
}

#header {overflow: hidden;}
```

#### Preview

[image]

#### Fiddle: http://jsbin.com/setipusabihu/1